# Detect mouse directly over border in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have a simple UserControl whose direct Child element is a border:-

```
 <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <Grid>...Content here...</Grid>
 </Border>
```

How can I detect that the mouse is over the border area, that is the 5 pixel border itself?  While the mouse is there I want to flip the border brush to another color.  When the mouse moves into the main Grid content I want to border brush to flip back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by placing a style on the Border and using a [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_triggers).

Note that you need to set the normal color in the Style, since setting it directly on the Border would set a local value that overrides the trigger.

```
<Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="5">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Grid>...Content here...</Grid>
</Border>
```

You could also put the Style in a resource dictionary so that you can share it among multiple Border elements:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderGreenOnHover">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="5"
        Style="{StaticResource borderGreenOnHover}">
    <Grid>...Content here...</Grid>
</Border>
```

---

If the mouse is inside the border, the trigger will not fire.  This is because the default Background for a Border is null, not Transparent, so the background area will not respond to [hit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).  If you set the Border.Background property to Transparent or to another Brush, then the trigger would fire if the mouse is anywhere over the Border.

If you want a non-null Background for the Border but you only want the trigger to fire when the mouse is over the border area, you can use [IsMouseDirectlyOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismousedirectlyover.aspx) instead of IsMouseOver, which will be false if the mouse is over a child element.  You could then set the Background on the Grid to Transparent so that the mouse is always over the grid.  (Really, if you wanted the contents to have a background color then it would be easier to just set it on the Grid.)

Comment: I'm wondering here but, the way I suggested it. Is it not really the WPF-way or? I'm still learning WPF you see and I'm basically used to WinForms :P. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when the mouse moves over the inner Grid content?

Comment: Nothing, it's still in the border so the IsMouseOver value is still true.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: The trigger will not fire, because that part of the Border element is not drawn and so is invisible to hit testing.  See me edit for a more long-winded explanation.

Comment: @Niels: In my opinion, this is a more WPF way to do it.  It is more declarative and you can more easily re-use the functionality by sharing the Style object, while event handlers can only be used in one file.  One advantage of Triggers over event-driven code like you wrote is that the framework will remember the previous value and restore it.  This even works if there are multiple triggers or if the base value changed while the triggers were active, which is logic that is easy to get wrong if you hand-write it every time.

Comment: The `IsMouseDirectlyOver` is the clue I needed, that does what I'm after. I spend most of my time in Silverlight but I don't want to be limited to Silverlight approaches when WPF may have a better approach which in this case it does.

Answer (score 0):

This can be checked with the MouseEnter & MouseLeave events from the border.

Xaml:

```
<Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Transparent" MouseEnter="border_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="border_MouseLeave">
    <Grid>...Content here...</Grid>
</Border>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Border hoveredBorder= (Border)sender;
    hoveredBorder.BorderBrush= Brushes.Yellow;
}

private void border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Border hoveredBorder= (Border)sender;
    hoveredBorder.BorderBrush= Brushes.Black;
}
```

Edit: I used Border hoveredBorder= (Border)sender; so you can use these events for more than just one border. If you don't want this you can just remove that line & get the desired border straight in.

Edit2: [Example Application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3380098/Stackoverflow/Stackoverflow.rar)

Comment: This doesn't work because MouseLeave doesn't fire as the mouse moves into the inner content.

Comment: I've created a WPF-Application and have copy pasted the code and for me it does work, however i have the border in a Window not a User Control, let me test this now.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a link to the example application. If this is not what you meant my apoligies :).